# How to fix [Errno 11004] get addrinfo failed error in Python 3

Tags: python-requests

I'm attempting to POST data to an API that catalogs store inventory.  However, no matter what angle I take I get some kind of error. Eventually someone at the company sent me a "working" sample of code in python3 to so I can try and get off the ground here. But to no avail.

I've been able to get other API projects running so I was feeling confident in tackling this one but I couldn't have been more wrong.  I'm able to get an authorization token using postman so I know I'm able to establish a connection and my credentials are good.  I've checked environment variables for proxies, scoured stackoverflow and just haven't found anything the helps me with this issue.

```py
import requests

url = "api_url_here"

payload = "{\n\t\"data\": { \n\t\t\"type\": \"catalogs\",\n\t\t\"attributes\": {\n\t\t\t\"listing_id\": my_id\n\t\t}\n\t}\n}"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/vnd.api+json",
    'Accept': "application/vnd.api+json",
    'Authorization': "Bearer my_token_here"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Instead of my payload being posted I get the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api_url_here', port=***): Max retries exceeded with url: **** (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02CA0570>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

Obviously I've removed any potentially sensitive data but nothing I've censored should be altering the outcome of the script. Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like a name resolution problem. Can you ping the host from `api_url_here`?

Comment: Yes, I can ping the host address

Comment: It doesn't look like you are misusing requests, so my best guess is that you have some environmental issue. Maybe you have proxy variables set (http_proxy, https_proxy) and the proxy is not reachable? Maybe you have some firewall denying you to connect toward the port you have redacted out of the traceback? Can you `telnet hostname port`?

Comment: Yep just tested it all clear on the port connection. Also I found a stack overflow question mentioning proxies and environment variables I checked that and couldn't find anything so I think I'm good on that font as well.

Comment: Well @petre it turns out the API I've been working with provided me with the wrong URL and didn't realize it until now.  I appreciate your help anyway.

Comment: Glad if it helped, @Micah.